# Oracle SQL update every nth row

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

To do some testing on a new table field, I'd like to fake-up some values on existing records in my test database. I want to assign a value to every 8th record in a table. I can easily select every 8th record using this syntax:

```
select *
from 
  (select rownum rn
    , jeffs_field_to_update
  from jeff)
where mod(rn, 8) = 0;
```

However, I'm fairly new to SQL, and I can't seem to be able to convert this to an update statement. I see a lot of answers here about selecting nth records, but I've already got that. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your table have a primary key?  What ordering governs "every 8th record" or don't care which rows are updated?

Comment: I ended up using Mikhail's answer, but to answer your question, I didn't really care which were updated - I just wanted a sizable subset, distributed throughout the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to join this to UPDATE statement on any key in the table. For example, if you have an  unique id column, update statement will look like this:

```
update jeff
set jeffs_field_to_update = value
where id in
(select id
from 
  (select rownum rn
    , jeff.id
  from jeff)
where mod(rn, 8) = 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

A shorter answer:

```
UPDATE jeff 
SET jeffs_field_to_update = value 
WHERE mod(DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_ROW_NUMBER(ROWID), 8)=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table has a unique id to identify each row, you can do something like this:

```
update jeff
    set . . .
    where id in (select id
                 from (select rownum as rn, id
                       from jeff
                      )
                 where mod(rn, 8) = 0
                )
```

You should also be able to do this with an inline updatable view (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/view-updatability.html)):

```
update (select jeffs_field_to_update
        from  (select rownum rn, jeffs_field_to_update
              from jeff)
        where mod(rn, 8) = 0
       ) toupdate
    set . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

even without the key, you can use rowid in oracle for this purpose.

```
update mytable
set mycol = new_value
where rowid in
(select rowid from 
  (select rownum rn, id from mytable)
where mod(rn, 8) = 0)
```